# When does a function $d:A\times A \to \mathbb R$ will not be a metric, due to violation of symmetry property

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

*Definition of Metric* --
Let, $A$ be a non-empty set. A function $d:A\times A \to \mathbb R$ is said to be a metric on $A$, if the following conditions are satisfied,

1. for all $x,y\in A$, $d(x,y)≥0 \land d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$ 【 Positiveness Property 】
2. for all $x,y\in A$, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$  【 Symmetry Property 】
3. for all $x,y,z\in A$, $d(x,y)≤d(x,z)+d(z,y)$  【 Triangle Inequality 】

In graduation level, we have questions like,

> 'Check that the given function $d:A\times A \to \mathbb R$ is a metric on $A$ or not: $d(x,y)=.........$, for $x,y\in A$.'

The questions, which we usually get, holds the symmetry property & which are not metric, they either violate the Positivity property or the triangle inequality.
Can you give me such an example where the function $d$ is not a metric, only due to the violation of symmetry property?

Comment: Do you looking for a function $d:A\times A\to \mathbb R$ such that $d$ is positive definite, satisfies the triangle inequality, and violates symmetry?

Comment: See [Quasimetrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics)

Comment: Yes I am looking for such an example.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just started studying Matric Space, so I was unaware of the thing called Quasimetric.

Comment: If you are looking for an example where **only** symmetry property is violated then the function $d:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(x,y)=x-y$ gives a good example. If this is not what you had in mind, you may edit the last sentence of your question by, "Can you give me such an example where the function $d$ is not a metric, only due to the violation of symmetry property?"

Answer (score 1):

As a very simple example, let $A=\{a,b\}$ have two elements and define $d(a,a)=d(b,b)=0$, $d(a,b)=1$ and $d(b,a)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

A more interesting function is $$d(x,y) = \max \{ x-y,0 \}$$
for $x,y$ real.

Answer (score 0):

Take a path-connected directed graph $G$ and let the distance between two nodes on the graph be the length of the shortest path joining them.